# Probability of being picked more than once in a simple random sample.

Tags: probability

A school has $500$ girls and $500$ boys. A simple random sample is obtained by selecting names from a box (with replacement) to a get a sample of $10$.

Find the probability of someone being picked more than once.

My working is: 
\begin{align}
P(\text{being picked more than once}) &= 1 - P(\text{not being picked}) - P(\text{being picked exactly once})\\
&=1 - \left(\frac{999}{1000}\right)^{10} - 10\left(\frac{1}{1000}\right)\left(\frac{999}{1000}\right)^9 = 0.00004476
\end{align}
However, this is not correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for the probability that a certain person is chosen more than once, or the probability that there is someone who is chosen more than once?

Comment: I think just ‘someone’, not a particular person. Does that mean I have to multiply the answer by 1000?

Comment: You would not simply multiply by $1000,$ because the events are not disjoint: more than one person could be picked more than once.

Comment: @DavidK how would you go about this problem?

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as the Birthday Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation on the Birthday Problem, with names instead of birthdays and drawings from the hat instead of people in a room.

The answer is $1$ minus the probability that all ten names are different,
which is the product of the probabilities that the $n$th name is different from all previous names, given that all previous names were unique.
The probability for the $n$th name is $\frac{1000 + 1 - n}{1000},$ so the answer is

$$ \frac{1000}{1000} \cdot \frac{999}{1000}
\cdot \frac{998}{1000} \cdot \frac{997}{1000}
\cdot \frac{996}{1000} \cdot \frac{995}{1000}
\cdot \frac{994}{1000} \cdot \frac{993}{1000}
\cdot \frac{992}{1000} \cdot \frac{991}{1000}
= \frac{1000!}{1000^{10}\,990!}.$$

Comment: Aha! That is the correct answer. Thank you. Just out of interest, how would you calculate the probability of a particular student being picked? I will approve your answer though anyway, many thanks!

Comment: For a given student to be chosen more than once, I think your calculation is correct.

Comment: I mean the probability of any one student being picked (it is a little different I think).

Comment: Suppose one of the boys is named George Kettle. George Kettle has a $\left(\frac{999}{1000}\right)^{10}$ chance not to be chosen at all, and a $10\left(\frac{1}{1000}\right)\left(\frac{999}{1000}\right)^9$ chance to be chosen exactly once. The chance that George Kettle is chosen more than once is $1$ minus the sum of those two probabilities.

Comment: Interesting, my book says it should be 0.00996, which is exceptionally close to your second expression (and the expression I also thought was correct). I think I will assume it is a typo

Answer (score -1):

Probability of anybody being picked more than once:

$$
\frac{\binom{10^{3}}{10}\times 10!}{\left(10^{3}\right)^{10}}
$$

Probability of a particular person being picked more than once:

$$
1-\frac{\left(10^{3}-1\right)^{10}+10\times\left(10^{3}-1\right)^{9}}{\left(10^{3}-1\right)^{10}}
$$

Comment: Isn't the first one the probability that _nobody_ is chosen more than once? In the second formula, I think the denominator is incorrect; the result is negative.